# Building Sinch from CocoaPods

Tags: ios, ios7, cocoapods, sinch

Has any tried building the latest Sinch (sinch.com) SDK through Cocoapods? Version 3.0.0.

I'm getting the following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SINOutgoingMessage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MessageThreadViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Sinch", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SinchClient.o
      (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SinchClient)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And wondering if anyone knows the fix?

Thanks!
Charlie

Comment: It is fairly straight forward. Did your pod install without any error?

Comment: Yes, pod installed fine.

Comment: Can you verify that the Sinch.framework has been properly added as part of the Pods.xcodeproj?     


Can you verify that `-framework Sinch` is part of OTHER_LDFLAGS in your Pods/Pods.xcconfig?

Comment: Ending up going the non cocoapods route - I can dig in more next week on cocoapods if it's helpful.

Comment: @CharlieWhite hi have u solve this issue? I've managed to build using CocoaPods with some help from Sinch.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do the things belove anymore. It is fixed by Sinch. Check the cjensen's answer.

In [here](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/minichat-ios-messaging-app/) there is an official tutorail from Sinch and it says [image: Sinch]

Try removing i386 from Architectures and run again.

Comment: typo in blog, clone it from here https://github.com/sinch/ios-messaging-tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Update, we have now released arm64 build so for new projects you should not have to change archs anymore.

Update you pods build settings and you should be fine.

Christan